# How do I get the desired output from my table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not that good at SQL so I am stuck with this query. I want the output:

```
employee id, employee name, manager name
```

(the manager of Kyle is 2 i.e Jones, and manager of Jones is 3 i.e David and so on)

```
Emp ID      Emp Name       ManagerID
  1          Kyle            2
  2          Jones           3
  3          David           4
  4          Henry           5
  5          John            1
```

What query should I write to get this output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to join the same table again with a different alias name

```
select e.empId, e.EmpName, m.EmpName as manager
from employees e
left join employees m on e.ManagerID = m.EmpID
```

If you use a `left join` then you get all employees, even if they do not have a manager.
If you use an `inner join` you will get only employees having a manager.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join your employee table with employee means self join. 
If you want employees with their manager then you can use below query.

```
select e.empId, e.EmpName, m.EmpName as manager_name
from employees e
inner join employees m on e.ManagerID = m.EmpID
```